# Continuing during an exception in a try/except statement

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-datareader

I have read numerous StackOverflow threads about looping during try/except statements, using else and finally, if/else statements, and while statements, but none of them address what I want. That or I don't know how to utilise that information to get what I want done.

Basically, I am trying to get adjusted closing stock prices for various companies on a given date. I pasted some dummy data in the code block below to demonstrate (NOTE: you'll have to install pandas and pandas_datareader to get the dummy code to run). The `get_stock_adj_close` function returns the adj_close price given a ticker and date. The `dummy_dataframe` contains 4 companies with their tickers and random dates. And the `add_days` function takes a date and adds any number of days. I would like to append the adjusted close stock prices for each company in the dataframe on the listed date into the `stock_prices` list.

Because the yahoo stock price database isn't that reliable for older entries and because some dates fall on days when the market is closed, whenever a price isn't available it raises a `KeyError: 'Date'`. Thus, what I would like to do is keep adding days indefinitely until it finds a date where a price does exist. The problem is it only adds the day once and then raises the same `KeyError`. I want it to keep adding days until it finds a day where the database has a stock price available and then return back to the dataframe and keep going with the next row. Right now the whole thing breaks on the first GM date (fourth row), which raises the `KeyError` and the fifth row/second GM date is ignored. Any help is appreciated!

Dummy data:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def add_days(d, num_days):
    return d + timedelta(days=num_days)
def get_stock_adj_close(ticker, chosen_date):
    stock_df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start = chosen_date, end = chosen_date)
    return stock_df.iloc[0]['Adj Close']

d = {'TICKER': ['AMD','AMD','CHTR','GM'], 'DATE': [datetime(2020,2,4), datetime(2019,2,8),datetime(2019,1,31), datetime(2010,4,7)]}
dummy_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

stock_prices = []

for i, row in dummy_dataframe.iterrows():
    given_date = row['DATE']
    try:
        stock_price = get_stock_adj_close(row['TICKER'], given_date)
        print(stock_price)
        stock_prices.append(stock_price)
    except KeyError:
        given_date = add_days(given_date,1)
        stock_price = get_stock_adj_close(row['TICKER'], given_date)
        stock_prices.append(stock_price)

print(stock_prices)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think while loop will help you. For example:

```
for i, row in dummy_dataframe.iterrows():
    given_date = row['DATE']
    stock_price_found = False
    while not stock_price_found:
        try:
            stock_price = get_stock_adj_close(row['TICKER'], given_date)
            print(stock_price)
            stock_prices.append(stock_price)
            stock_price_found = False
        except KeyError:
            given_date = add_days(given_date,1)
```

Or you can also use *while True* together with *break*:

```
for i, row in dummy_dataframe.iterrows():
    given_date = row['DATE']
    while True:
        try:
            stock_price = get_stock_adj_close(row['TICKER'], given_date)
            print(stock_price)
            stock_prices.append(stock_price)
            break
        except KeyError:
            given_date = add_days(given_date,1)
```

Don't forget to make sure that you are not stuck in indefinite loop, would be also helpful some other exit conditions from while loop, for example, after 10 failures.

Comment: Does it answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! I would upvote you but I cannot at my current level, sorry!